# Get base interface of an interface by reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I get base interface of an interface by reflection? I have tried to call BaseType propery, but value of It is null. After that I need to find generic type class of interface.

I need to find `Foo` type from the type of `ISomeInterfaceForItem` on this sample.

```
Type oType = typeof(ISomeInterfaceForItem);

Type oBase = oType.BaseType; // equals null

public interface ISomeInterfaceForItem: ISomeInterface<Foo>
{        
}

public interface ISomeInterface<T>
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet for pointing my mistake. I have corrected question.

Comment: That an interface *seems* to have a BaseType is an illusion that's created by C# syntax.  Nothing like that, you merely inherited the need to also implement the other interface(s).  Use oType.GetInterfaces() instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the inherited interfaces using [`GetInterface()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterface) and enumerate the generic arguments using [`GetGenericArguments()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericarguments):

```
Type generic = typeof(I2).GetInterface("ISomeInterfaceForItem`1")?.
                          GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 8):

Interfaces do not participate in inheritance, so `BaseType` makes no sense. Instead, you need to see what kinds of interfaces are implemented by the given type:

```
oType
  .FindInterfaces((t, _) => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() 
                            == typeof(ISomeInterface<>), null)
  .Select(i => i.GetGenericArguments().First())
```

Note that one class can implement multiple variants of `ISomeInterface<>` - e.g. `class MyClass : ISomeInterface<Foo>, ISomeInterface<Bar>` - that's why the result of the sample above is an enumerable of types, rather than just a single type.